# pandoc markdown to docx - keep list on one page

Tags: ms-word, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown list like so:

`*  Question A
   -  Answer 1
   -  Answer 2
   -  Answer 3`

I need to ensure that all the answers (1 - 3) appear on the same page as Question A when I convert the markdown document to docx using pandoc. **How can I do this?**

Comment: I know nothing about pandoc, but I do know that, ideally, Word would handle this using styles, where the Question style would have the paragraph setting "Keep with Next". the Answer style would have this as well. A third style, for the last entry, would NOT have the setting activated. In addition, all three styles would have the paragraph setting "Keep together" activated. Another possible approach would be to have the entire set in a Table cell with the setting "Allow row to break across pages" deactivated. Perhaps you can find the pandoc equivalents that will migrate successfully to Word...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use custom styles in your Markdown and then define those styles in a custom docx template.

It's important to note that Pandoc's [documentation](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) states (emphasis added):

> Because pandoc’s intermediate representation of a document is less
>   expressive than many of the formats it converts between, **one should
>   not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other.**
>   Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, **but
>   not formatting details**...

Of course, Markdown has no concept of "pages" or "page breaks," so that is not something Pandoc can handle by default. However, Pandoc is aware of docx styles. As the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-styles-in-docx) explains:

> By default, pandoc’s docx output applies a predefined set of styles
>   for blocks such as paragraphs and block quotes, and uses largely
>   default formatting (italics, bold) for inlines. This will work for
>   most purposes, especially alongside a `reference.docx` file. However, if
>   you need to apply your own styles to blocks, or match a preexisting
>   set of styles, pandoc allows you to define custom styles for blocks
>   and text using `divs` and `spans`, respectively.
>
> If you define a `div` or `span` with the attribute `custom-style`, pandoc
>   will apply your specified style to the contained elements. So, for
>   example using the `bracketed_spans` syntax,
>
> ```
> [Get out]{custom-style="Emphatically"}, he said.
> ```
>
> would produce a docx file with “Get out” styled with character style
>   `Emphatically`. Similarly, using the `fenced_divs` syntax,
>
> Dickinson starts the poem simply:
>
> ```
> ::: {custom-style="Poetry"}
> | A Bird came down the Walk---
> | He did not know I saw---
> :::
> ```
>
> would style the two contained lines with the `Poetry` paragraph style.
>
> If the styles are not yet in your `reference.docx`, they will be defined
>   in the output file as inheriting from `normal` text. If they are already
>   defined, pandoc will not alter the definition.

If you don't want to define the style manually, but would like it applied to every list automatically (or perhaps to every list which follows a specific pattern), you could define a custom [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) which applied the style(s) to every matching element in the document.

Of course, that only adds the style names to the output. You still need to define the styles (tell Word how to display elements assigned those styles). As the [documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers) for the `--reference-doc` option explains :

> For best results, the reference docx should be a modified version of a
>   docx file produced using pandoc. The contents of the reference docx
>   are ignored, but its stylesheets and document properties (including
>   margins, page size, header, and footer) are used in the new docx. If
>   no reference docx is specified on the command line, pandoc will look
>   for a file `reference.docx` in the user data directory (see `--data-dir`).
>   If this is not found either, sensible defaults will be used.
>
> To produce a custom `reference.docx`, first get a copy of the default
>   `reference.docx`: `pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx >
>   custom-reference.docx`. Then open `custom-reference.docx` in Word, modify
>   the styles as you wish, and save the file.

Of course, when modifying the `custom-reference.docx` in Word, you can add your new custom style which you have used in your Markdown. As @CindyMeister points out in a comment:

> Word would handle this using styles, where the Question style would
>   have the paragraph setting "Keep with Next". the Answer style would
>   have this as well. A third style, for the last entry, would NOT have
>   the setting activated. In addition, all three styles would have the
>   paragraph setting "Keep together" activated.

Finally, when using pandoc to convert your Markdown to a Word docx file, use the option `--reference-doc=custom-reference.docx` and your custom style definitions will be included in the generated docx file. As long as you also properly identify which elements in the Markdown document get which styles, your should have a list which doesn't get broken across a page break as long at the entire list fits on one page.

Comment: I still haven't figured out the Word styles issue though.  I wonder if it is more complicated because we are dealing with lists?  I modified the styles so that the Question style is "Keep with Next", as is the Answer style, and the last answer option has "Keep with Next" deactivated.  All of them have "keep lines together", but I still get instances where the question and the block of answers are on different pages.